# How do i get a loading screen while i fetch images from api?

Tags: flutter, dart, loading

> I want a loading screen when i shake screen and 10 more images loads from api.

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _shakePlugin = FlutterShakePlugin(
      onPhoneShaken: (){
        //do stuff on phone shake
        setState(() {
          
          count=count+10;
           
           
        });
      },
    )..startListening();
  }

Future<String> getjsondata() async {
    try {
      
      var response = await http.get(
          'https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?per_page=${count}&client_id=TcAQEO3JoMG90U7Rl-YUiDo1x9XbZukzMOMQhxUVCV4&query=${_search}');
      setState(() {
        var converted = json.decode(response.body);
        data = converted['results'];
      });
      
    } catch (e) {}
    return 'success';
  }
```

> Whenever i increment the count by 10,i need a loading widget to show until it fetches the images from api.

Comment: Which language/framework are you using and on which platform? Web, android, ios, or windows?

Comment: Im using flutter framework.

Comment: I knew it was flutter, btw how do you install flutter in windows 10? How did you do that? I tried to install it on m windows but failed. pls tell me how to install it

Comment: i didnot, im using it on linux to build apps for mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FutureBuilder` to handle the different snapshot conditions and connection states to show different widgets

Answer (score 0):

Use FutureBuillder with below code

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: getjsondata(),
        builder: (_, dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Container(.....) // Show your images here & take data using dataSnapshot.data
          }
        },
      ),
```